# What is /invokerPRAID?

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-bridge

I'm making a Universal Windows App designed for entertainment purposes and one of its tasks is to run a locally installed game.

I've done all the configurations of the .appxmanifest to run a `fullTrustProcess` and placed the `.exe` in the `/Assets` folder in order for it to be accessible. 
But once I try to run the `.exe` through the App with

```
await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
```

I get this error message: `Error! Failed to open InvokerPRAID: with errno 22` 
It's really strange since it doesn't appear to throw this error with every `.exe` I try to run.
The problem is I don't know what this error means and I can't seem to find information on it anywhere.
If anyone can shed some light on the matter I'd be very grateful.

Comment: The Microsoft code that implements UWP has OutputDebugString() statements to generate diagnostic messages, visible in a debugger.  That is not *supposed* to happen in release code, but error diagnostics are always hard to come by in UWP.  Most any mishap in C++ code turns into a vague "it did not work" error in (say) Javascript.  There's a Microsoft programmer somewhere that might have a cue, the error code doesn't say more than "bad command".  If you see a C++ exception in the Output window then that might provide better info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the FullTrustProcoessLauncher you can only launch an EXE that is in your package, not an arbitrary game on the system. If this is your goal then you can include a simple EXE in your package that you launch via FullTrustProcessLauncher, which will then in turn launch your game (via Process.Start or ShellExecute). See also my blog post on this topic: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/

The "/InvokerPRAID" parameter is passed by FullTrustProcessLauncher to the EXE and indicates the ID of the app that has triggered the launch.

This ID is specified in the appxmanifest.xml file:

```
<Application ID="[PRAID]" ...>
```

Btw, PRAID stands for "package relative app id".